# Firefox, wmode and fscommand

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox

I'm using SWFObject to embed flash on my site.

```
var so = new SWFObject("file.swf", "file", "100%", "100%", "8", "#FFFFFF");
so.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
so.addParam("allowscriptaccess", "always");
so.write(container);
```

This works like a charm in all browsers as far I can tell, but I'm also using fscommand from flash, and thus I'm having a function:

```
function file_DoFSCommand(command, args) {
    alert("It works!");
}
```

And this also works in all browsers I tested, except Firefox on windows, where the file_DoFSCommand doesn't get called (but the flash is displayed). Firefox mac and other browsers display "It works!" as expected. Very strange. If I remove "wmode", "opaque" it suddenly works, but then my css menu gets below the Flash so that's not an option. 
wmode = transparent doesn't seem to change anything.

Setting the so.addParam("allowscriptaccess", "never"); makes the other browsers behave like FF on windows when wmode is set.

Any suggestions why FF won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Theo.T, thanks for the tip. It didn't solve my problem though, but searching around for how to use ExternalInterface led me to a page saying IE wouldn't receive calls from flash when the container was hidden. My container wasn't hidden, but the height was set to 0:

```
<div id="flashcontainer" style="height:0">
```

Setting the height to 1px solved the problem and Firefox now successfully receives the calls from Flash

Comment: Ha, that's an interesting one.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, try using ExternalInterface instead of FSCommand (depreciated somehow). There's a lot of examples around in SO already.